# Python loop files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the script below that basically queries an api that transcribes an audio. However at the moment I am putting one audio at a time, I would like to help because inside the 'audios' folder I have a list of .wav files. What would be the best way to read all .wav files

```
import requests

from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now()
date = date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')

session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False

dados = {'login': 'teste'}
nome_arquivo = (r'audios/RE1a2aea7875d5286c4cbb6d8910cba3cf.wav')
arquivo = {'file': open(nome_arquivo, 'rb')}

log = open(r'log/transcricao.log', 'a')
resposta = session.post(f'http://localhost:8000/', data=dados, files=arquivo)     
print(date, resposta.text, file=log)
log.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

The [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module provides useful function for accesing file names that match a pattern:

```py
import glob

for filename in glob.glob("audios/*.wav"):
    with open(filename) as audio_file:
        # Do your processing
```